# Alternative to List.Include in EF

Tags: entity-framework

I am having circular reference due to the EF code below. I have a Parent table with 2 childs and their grandchildren respectively. Is there any alternative to using Include, as I read something about Navigation property and it includes the parents in each of the child, causing the serialization having circular reference problem.

Error Message: 
A circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type 'Product'.

This part is only to get retrieval and I don't need the parent reference back to each of the child. I debug inside and saw that inside each of the child, it has the parent reference back.

```
  var query = db.Products.Include(c => c.ProductTriggers.Select(b => b.ProductTriggerItems))
                    .Include(d => d.ProductsExtra.Select(e => e.ProductAllotments.Select(m => m.ProductAllotmentDetails))).AsNoTracking();

        return query.ToList();
```

Product Class

```
 public partial class Product
{
    public Product()
    {
        this.ProductExtras = new HashSet<ProductExtra>();
        this.ProductTriggers = new HashSet<ProductTrigger>();
    }

    public int ProductID { get; set; }
    public string ProductCode { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ProductProduct> ProductExtras { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ProductTrigger> ProductTriggers { get; set; }
}
```

ProductExtra Class

```
 public partial class ProductExtra
{
    public ProductExtra()
    {
        this.ProductAllotments = new HashSet<ProductAllotment>();
    }

    public int ProductExtraID { get; set; }
    public int ProductID { get; set; }


    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ProductAllotment> ProductAllotments { get; set; }
}
```

ProductAllotment Class

```
   public partial class ProductAllotment
{
    public ProductAllotment()
    {
        this.ProductAllotmentDetails = new HashSet<ProductAllotmentDetail>();
    }

    public int ProductAllotmentID { get; set; }
    public int ProductExtraID { get; set; }


    public virtual ProductExtra ProductExtra { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ProductAllotmentDetail> ProductAllotmentDetails { get; set; }
}
```

ProductTrigger Class

```
public partial class ProductTrigger
{
    public ProductTrigger()
    {
        this.AddOnTriggerItems = new HashSet<ProductTriggerItem>();
    }

    public int ProductTriggerID { get; set; }
    public int ProductID { get; set; }


    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ProductTriggerItem> ProductTriggerItems { get; set; }
}
```

ProductTriggerItem Class

```
public partial class ProductTriggerItem
{
    public int ProductTriggerItemID { get; set; }
    public int ProductTriggerID { get; set; }


    public virtual ProductTrigger ProductTrigger { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: can you put the code of the models?

Comment: Could you provide the error if one is generated too?

Comment: I create data transfer objects to serialize that simplify the database model and eliminate the circular references you are seeing try this article: [DTO with EF](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/data/using-web-api-with-entity-framework/part-5)

Comment: I'd seen that but is there examples for a parent with 2 childs and below each child has child too?